# using 'this' keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm confused as to why the code below will return `undefined`. If you `console.log(this)` you will get the myObj object and not the global window object. Therefore, 'this' is clearly pointing to the correct object to access the value of x and y yet it returns undefined. Here is the code:

```
var myObj = {
    takeTwoNums: function (x, y) {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}
myObj.takeTwoNums(1, 2);
```

Comment: `myObj` doesn't have an `x` property. Did you mean to do `console.log(x)`?

Comment: Yes, I know that `console.log(x)` will return 1. But why can't `this.x` see the `x` variable?

Comment: Because in there, `this.x` would reference a _property_ on the `myObj` object, which is not there. `this.x !== x`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your call to `takeTwoNums`, `this` refers to the same object that `myObj` refers to. That object doesn't have an `x` property. It has a `takeTwoNums` property, and a couple of properties it inherits from `Object.prototype` like `toString` and such, but no `x.`

The `x` is an *argument* to the method. You just reference it as `x`. Calling the method doesn't make `this` refer to an object that has the arguments as properties.

You may be confusing this with something like this:

```
function Thingy(x) {
    this.x = x;
}

// Then
var t = new Thingy(42);
```

In *that* case, because we used `new`, it created a new object and then called `Thingy` with `this` referring to that new object and we *created* a property on it called `x` that we initialized with the value of the argument `x`. But that's another thing entirely than just calling a function.

Comment: ok, that makes a lot of sense so the problem is I'm trying to access a variable that doesn't exist within the object construct because it is an argument that can only be passed in from outside the `myObj` object. Thus the variable must be defined within the object in order to use the 'this' keyword. Something like this: `var myObj = { x: 1, takeTwoNums: function () { console.log(this.x); }}myObj.takeTwoNums()`

Comment: @Haloor: Right. At which point we call it a *property*, rather than a *variable* (or *argument*), but it's much the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `this`. Instead, try this:

```
var myObj = {
    takeTwoNums: function (x, y) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
myObj.takeTwoNums(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is referring to the object, so by using `this.x` you're requesting the `x` of `myObj`. In other words, it's looking for `myObj.x`, which doesn't exist.

Here's a small reference guide for `this` in objects:

```
var myObj = {
    myVal: 3,
    takeTwoNums: function (x, y) {
        console.log(x);
    },
    takeThisNum: function (x, y) {
        console.log(this.x);
    },
    getVal: function() {
        console.log(myVal);
    },
    realGetVal: function() {
        console.log(this.myVal);
    }
}
myObj.takeTwoNums(1, 2); // Logs 1
myObj.takeThisNum(1, 2); // Logs undefined
myObj.getVal(); // Logs undefined
myObj.realGetVal(); // Logs 3
```